# Windows 7 other user

Tags: windows-7, window, user

I want to know how to log on to a hidden account. I know that you can set it so that you will have to enter the username and password but I want the welcome screen that will show the usernames.

I know there is a option that is called "other user" but I dont know how to show it. If you are connected to a DNS server it will show but is there a way that you dont have to be connected to a DNS server? I have Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: I think you mean "domain" (as in Active Directory domains), not "DNS server". Despite similarities in name, AD domains have nothing to do with "being connected to a DNS server".

Answer (score 1):

Changing one option in secpol you could log in with your hidden account

```
secpol.msc
Local Policies\Security Options
    Interactive logon: Display user info..............  Do not displ............
```

To show a user you must put this entry in the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList\

and add a DWORD with the user name and value 1.

Comment: when I try to go on secpol.msc is has an error

Comment: @winter4w execute it as an administrator. If you have UAC disabled you get an error instead of a prompt for consent. The workaround is use the comand runas or right click and select "run as administrator".

Comment: I did that but i still got an error. the error sayes Failed to open Group Policy Object on this coumputer. You may not have the appropriate rights. Details: Unspecified error

Comment: @winter4w what type of user account do you have?

Comment: i have a adminstrator